# Need help to understand accelerometer code

Tags: java, android

I have read through a lot of code but I do not understand how you can make an image move using the accelerometer sensor, I understand how to register it but I do not understand how to actually make an image or a shape draw move in sync with the accelerometer axis, I am using android java to do this. Please can someone help me as I am really struggling. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's the code to register a listener (I know you said you've done this already, but it can never hurt):

```
private void enableAccelerometerListening() {
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(COntext.SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener), sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(
Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

private void disableAccelerometerListening() {
if (sensorManager != null) {
sesnsorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEVentListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER));
sensorManager = null;
}}
```

You will need a couple fields just below your class declaration:

```
private SesnsorManager sensorManager;
private float acceleration;
private float currentAcceleration;
private float lastAcceleration;
private static final int ACCELERATION_THRESHOLD = 15000;
```

Here is the event handler, which gets very close to what you need help with:

```
    private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    public void onSesnsorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];

lastAcceleration = currentAcceleration; //save previous accel value

currentAcceleration = x*x + y*y + z*z;

acceleration = currentAcceleration * (currentAcceleration - lastAcceleration); // calc the change in acceleration

//if the accel is above a certain threshold:
if (acceleration > ACCELERATION_THRESHOLD) {
//MAKE YOUR CODE HERE THAT RESPONDS TO ACCELERATION EVENTS
//Note, your accel threshold should be determined by trial and error on a number of devices
}
}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy {}

};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I am currently looking over and understanding your code, if it is helpful I will mark up your answer

Answer (score 0):

Also, I'll try to address some of your animation needs, though I am much more spotty in this area. I imagine that what you need to do is make your image move as the accelerometer detects moves. The image will have to be moved via an animation, rather than the accelerometer directly. So say 'spot' is your image, okay? (the code below both adds a spot and sets up its animations(which are not directly tied to the accelerometer, but I hope this will be helpful nonetheless):

```
public void addSpot() {

int x = random.nextInt(viewWidth - SPOT_DIAMETER);
int y = random.nextInt(viewHeight = SPOT_DIAMETER);
int x2 = random.nextInt(viewWidth - SPOT_DIAMETER);
int y2 = random.nextInt(viewWidth - SPOT_DIAMETER);

final ImageView spot = (ImageView) layoutFinlater.inflate(R.layout.untouched, null);
spot.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(SPOT_DIAMETER, SPOT_DIAMETER));
spot.setX(x);
spot.setY(y);
```

Well right here is where I think you could start doing something with the accelerometer events...

As you saw in my other response above,

```
if (acceleration > ACCELERATION_THRESHOLD) {
spot.animate().x(x2).y(y2).setDuration(animationTime);
```

animationTime will just be something in milliseconds that you feel is appropriate, and don't forget to take care of importing the necessary packages.